# Attempted to associate a different object with id (when saving object into ravendb)

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

I have following code where I creating new object and trying to save into raven database.
...

```
{
     foreach (var url in urls)
     {
        MyUrl u = new MyUrl {
        Id = url.Id,
        Url = url.Url
     };
     urlsCollection.Add(u);
     retrievedUrl = new RetrievedUrl {
        Id = url.Id,
        Url = url.Url
    };
    RavenSession.Store(retrievedUrl); //exception is thrown
    RavenSession.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm getting

> Raven.Client.Exceptions.NonUniqueObjectException

on  `RavenSession.Store(retrievedUrl);`

with following exception message

```
An exception of type 'Raven.Client.Exceptions.NonUniqueObjectException' 
occurred in Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll but was not handled in user code

 Additional information: Attempted to associate a different object 
 with id 'RetrievedUrl/361'.
```

Comment: Where is the `url` object in `retrievedUrl = new RetrievedUrl {
        Id = url.Id,
        Url = url.Url
    };` coming from?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are trying to save (at least) two different objects with the same Id and that is not possible. RavenDB automatically creates unique ids when storing new documents, however, if you explicitly define the document Id, that will be used instead. Some more info in [saving new document in raven](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/Csharp/client-api/basic-operations/saving-new-document).

Answer (score 0):

This means you already have a different object in the session with the same id. The fix for me was to use a new session. Alternatively you could copy over the values as per [Update Document with external object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829986/update-document-with-external-object)