# Update Document with external object

Tags: ravendb

i have a database containing Song objects. The song class has > 30 properties.

My Music Tagging application is doing changes on a song on the file system. 
It then does a lookup in the database using the filename.

Now i have a Song object, which i created in my Tagging application by reading the physical file and i have a Song object, which i have just retrieved from the database and which i want to update.
I thought i just could grab the ID from the database object, replace the database object with my local song object, set the saved id and store it.
But Raven claims that i am replacing the object with a different object.

Do i really need to copy every single property over, like this?

dbSong.Artist = songfromFilesystem.Artist;

dbSong.Album = songfromFileSystem.Album;

Or are there other possibilities.

thanks,

Helmut

Edit:

I was a bit too positive. The suggestion below works only in a test program.
When doing it in my original code i get following exception:

```
Attempted to associate a different object with id 'TrackDatas/3452'
```

This is produced by following code:

```
try
  {
    originalFileName = Util.EscapeDatabaseQuery(originalFileName);
    // Lookup the track in the database
    var dbTracks = _session.Advanced.DocumentQuery<TrackData, DefaultSearchIndex>().WhereEquals("Query", originalFileName).ToList();
    if (dbTracks.Count > 0)
    {
      track.Id = dbTracks[0].Id;
      _session.Store(track);
      _session.SaveChanges();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    log.Error("UpdateTrack: Error updating track in database {0}: {1}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
  }
```

I am first looking up a song in the database and get a TrackData object in dbTracks.

The track object is also of type TrackData and i just put the ID from the object just retrieved and try to store it, which gives the above error.

I would think that the above message tells me that the objects are of different types, which they aren't.

The same error happens, if i use AutoMapper.

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you're trying: replace an existing object using just the ID. If it's not working, you might be doing something else wrong. (In which case, please show us your code.)

When it comes to updating existing objects in Raven, there are a few options:

Option 1: Just save the object using the same ID as an existing object:

```
var song = ... // load it from the file system or whatever
song.Id = "Songs/5"; // Set it to an existing song ID
DbSession.Store(song); // Overwrites the existing song
```

Option 2: Manually update the properties of the existing object.

```
var song = ...;
var existingSong = DbSession.Load<Song>("Songs/5");
existingSong.Artist = song.Artist;
existingSong.Album = song.Album;
```

Option 3: Dynamically update the existing object:

```
var song = ...;
var existingSong = DbSession.Load<Song>("Songs/5");
existingSong.CopyFrom(song);
```

Where you've got some code like this:

```
// Inside Song.cs
public virtual void CopyFrom(Song other)
{
    var props = typeof(Song)
        .GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(p => p.CanWrite);
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        var source = prop.GetValue(other);
        prop.SetValue(this, source);
    }
}
```

If you find yourself having to do this often, use a library like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Automapper can automatically copy one object to another with a single line of code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers.
I tried all the above possibilities including Automapper.

Found out that i had set the ID wrong.
Works perfect now

Comment: Glad to help. I'd appreciate it if you could mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Still having the error. Changed my original post with additional infos.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've posted some code, I see 2 things:

First, is there a reason you're using the Advanced.DocumentQuery syntax?

```
// This is advanced query syntax. Is there a reason you're using it?
var dbTracks = _session.Advanced.DocumentQuery<TrackData, DefaultSearchIndex>().WhereEquals("Query", originalFileName).ToList();
```

Here's how I'd write your code using standard LINQ syntax:

```
var escapedFileName = Util.EscapeDatabaseQuery(originalFileName);
// Find the ID of the existing track in the database.
var existingTrackId = _session.Query<TrackData, DefaultSearchIndex>()
   .Where(t => t.Query == escapedFileName)
   .Select(t => t.Id);
if (existingTrackId != null)
{
   track.Id = existingTrackId;
   _session.Store(track);
   _session.SaveChanges();
}
```

Finally, #2: what is track? Was it loaded via session.Load or session.Query? If so, that's not going to work, and it's causing your problem. If track is loaded from the database, you'll need to create a new object and save that:

```
 var escapedFileName = Util.EscapeDatabaseQuery(originalFileName);
// Find the ID of the existing track in the database.
var existingTrackId = _session.Query<TrackData, DefaultSearchIndex>()
   .Where(t => t.Query == escapedFileName)
   .Select(t => t.Id);
if (existingTrackId != null)
{
   var newTrack = new Track(...);
   newTrack.Id = existingTrackId;
   _session.Store(newTrack);
   _session.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: track is an object of TrackData, which was created by reading the Tag information from the e.g. mp3 file.
It contains the changes made to the music file.
And the changes should be stored in the database.

I'll try tommorow using your LINQ syntax

Comment: Did this fix your issue, @Helmut?

Comment: na, i can do what ever i want.
i was using your construct above. 
was creating a new TrackData object and used an existing id.

The store command gives me the above error.

Comment: Only thing that works, if i load the object from database,  assign each single property to the loaded db object and then store the db object.

Even using AutoMapper doesn't work. i have no idea, what the problem might be.

Comment: Do you set .UseOptimisticConcurrency anywhere? If so, what are you setting that to?

Comment: No, i am not using this.

Comment: Ok. I found it. I couldn't use the LINQ query to get the id, since ID is not in any of my indices. Because i was loading the object from the database to get the id, i still had a reference to it. i simply needed to use Evict on the object to release the reference to it in the session and then it worked.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Yep, I figured you were loading the object and then trying to replace it. That's why I asked where "what is track? Was it loaded via session.Load or session.Query? If so, that's not going to work, and it's causing your problem". Anyways, I'm glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This means you already have a different object in the session with the same id. The fix for me was to use a new session.